# tasks needs to be performed before registration is authenticated

Tags: android, firebase

Have a app that requires the user to fill out a form, being approved and then being authenticated when registering.

Basically, a driver is registering for an app but needs to complete a record check, submit a photo of their license and get it approved before their account is registered.

Any ideas as to how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the model of delivery (Uber, instacart, etc) and have a signup area in the app where user adds that information then waits to be approved before continuing to complete profile and officially be registered in the app.  You just need a storage implementation to hold users on the server side and a status.
You could decompile one of those model apps to get an idea.

Comment: Would i find this anywhere online like a tutorial?  I havent found one yet.

Comment: google for "delivery app tutorial", appypie has one even if you don't use the app builder it lays out the high level : https://www.appypie.com/how-to-create-food-delivery-app-with-app-builder-appy-pie

Comment: Haven't come across anything yet that i can follow.